# If statement Tableau

Tags: if-statement, tableau-api

I require an `IF` statement in Tableau to find certain people (players) who only played Sports & not Casino. The formulas I have tried are:

```
IF [Bet € for Calculation €]>0 THEN
IF [Product Vertical]="sport"  THEN
IF [Bet € for Calculation €]=0 THEN
IF [Product Vertical]="casino" THEN
THEN [Bet € for Calculation €] END
ELSE NULL
END
```

I have also tried an `AND` version, but both come out with errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to include brackets?

```
IF (([Bet € for Calculation €]>0)
   AND ([Product Vertical]="sport")  
   AND ([Bet € for Calculation €]=0)
   AND ([Product Vertical]="casino"))
   THEN [Bet € for Calculation €] 
ELSE NULL
END
```